# Задача "Игра". Валится на 8м тесте

Tags: c++, c

[Задача №38. Игра - 2 (ACMP.RU)](http://acmp.ru/?main=task&id_task=38).

Текст задачи:

> (Время: 1 сек. Память: 16 Мб Сложность: 60%) Вы любите играть в игры? Конечно, любите! Но про эту игру, возможно, ничего не знаете и не слышали даже. Что ж, расскажем о новой игре. На доске написана последовательность n целых чисел. Играют двое. На очередном ходе игрок выбирает число с правого или с левого края последовательности, затем это число стирается и последовательность становится на одно число меньше, а ход переходит к противнику. Выигрывает тот, кто наберет в сумме больше. Написать программу, определяющую победителя в конкретной игре, при условии, что игроки будут играть оптимально.
>
> Входные данные
>
> В первой строке входного файла INPUT.TXT записано целое число n (0 < n < 100). Во второй строке через пробел заданы n натуральных чисел, не превосходящих 1000.
>
> Выходные данные
>
> В единственную строку выходного файла OUTPUT.TXT нужно вывести 1, если победит первый игрок, 2 – если победит второй игрок и 0 – в случае ничьей.

Задача не проходит а 8м тесте, вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int n;
    freopen("INPUT.TXT", "r", stdin);
    freopen("OUTPUT.TXT", "w", stdout);
    int *a;
    a = new int[n];
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    int f = 0, s = 0, l, r, t;
    if (n % 2 != 0) {
        t = ((n - 1) / 2);
        s = a[t];
        l = t - 1;
        r = t + 1;
        bool flag = false;
        while (!flag) {
            if (a[l] > a[r]) {
                f += a[l];
                s += a[r];
            } else {
                f += a[r];
                s += a[l];
            }
            l--;
            r++;
            if (l == 0 || r == n) {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        l = (n - 1) / 2;
        r = l + 1;
        bool flag = false;
        while (!flag) {
            if (a[l] > a[r]) {
                f += a[l];
                s += a[r];
            } else {
                f += a[r];
                s += a[l];
            }
            l--;
            r++;
            if (l == 0 || r == n) {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (f > s)
        printf("1");
    if (f < s)
        printf("2");
    if (f == s)
        printf("0");
}
```

Comment: Интересен алгоритм в виде описания. Явно вариант "выбираем большее число из обоих краев последовательности" не велет к выигрышу. Расмотреть последовательности из одинаковых элементов, все элементы одинаковы, кроме одного (как в меньшую, так и в большую сторону, расположение отличающегося элемента может быть любое!!!!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Несложная задачка на динамику, смысл в том, чтобы просмотреть все возможные варианты ходов, аккумулируя предыдущие действия *(и тем самым избавляясь от экспоненты в сложности).*

---

Я не буду постить свой код решения *(вам, вероятно, интересно решить задачу самому)*, ниже приведен **комментарий другого автора по поводу того, как оформлять динамику в этой задаче:**

> Берем матрицу состояний a[n+1][n+1].
> Рассмотрим элемент a[i][j]. В данном
> случае i - это сколько чисел сняли
> слева в оригинальной посл-ти. j -
> сколько сняли справа. Начальное
> состояние - это a[0][0] - то есть
> ничего не сняли. Конечное состояние
> a[i][j], где i+j==n. В конечом
> состоянии мы сняли все числа и ходов
> больше нет.
>
> Кроме этого состояние содержит: 1)
> sum[0] - сумма чисел набранная 0-ым
> игроком 2) sum[1] - сумма чисел
> набранная 1-ым игроком
>
> Какой игрок ходит из данного состояния
> a[i][j] однозначно определяется по i,j
> Из состояния a[0][0] ходит 0-ой игрок.
> Из состояния a[1][0] ходит 1-ый игрок.
> Из состояния a[0][1] ходит 1-ый игрок.
>
> Кроме этого удобно в каждое состояние
> записать наилучший вариант хода:
> best_var. Очевидно что из каждого
> состояния a[i][j] мы можем снять либо
> слева число, тогда мы попадем в
> a[i+1][j] - это будет вариант хода
> best_var == 0 либо мы снимем число
> справа - тогда мы попадем в a[i][j+1],
> это будет best_var == 1.
>
> **Начальное положение.** После снятия
> последнего числа мы будем в состоянии
> a[i][j], где i+j==n. Нужно заполнить
> все такие состояния.
>
> **Очередной ход.** Перебираем назад. Мы
> двигаемся по побочным диагоналям
> матрицы. for ( level= n-1; level>=0;
> level -- ) { // тут перебираем всем
> a[i][j], где i+j==level }
>
> Заполняем часть матрицы от побочной
> диагонали до левого верхнего угла.
>
> **Кто выиграл.** Обратим внимание на самое
> начальное состояние - a[0][0]. Если в
> этом состоянии sum[0] > sum[1], то
> значит выиграл 0-ой игрок. Если sum[0]
> < sum[1], то значит выиграл 1-ый
> игрок. Ну и остался последний вариант
> - если суммы равны, значит ничья.

---

Если есть вопросы, обращайтесь.